# one view controller appears on another view controller in iOS 5 and below versions

Tags: iphone, ipad, xcode4.5

I have a UItabbarController with two view controllers. When I click on the login button present in one view controller, it should take me to other tabbarController. When that happens I get the first view controller on the top of present tabbarcontroller and it looks like one on the other. It works fine in iPhone 6.0 simulator, but fails as described in the iPhone 5.0 simulator.

In appDelegate.m:

```
     - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                  state:(FBSessionState) state
                  error:(NSError *)error
  {
    switch (state) {
    case FBSessionStateOpen:
        if (!error) {




            if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
            {
                FLogin *flogin=[[FLogin alloc]initWithNibName:@"FLogin" bundle:nil];

                self.window.rootViewController=fblogin;  // I think because of this I m getting this issue


            }



        }

}
```

in flogin.m

```
   tab=[[[UITabBarController alloc]init]autorelease];
          ViewController *searchViewController=[[[ViewController   alloc]initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil]autorelease];
            Account *account=[[[Account alloc]initWithNibName:@"Account" bundle:nil]autorelease];
            account.title=@"My Account";



            tab.viewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:searchViewController,account,nil];
            for(UIViewController *tab1 in  tab.viewControllers)

            {
                if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]>5.0 ||[[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue]==5.0)
                {
                    [tab.tabBarItem setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                            [UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
                                                  forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                }
            }

            [self presentModalViewController:tab animated:NO];
```

Comment: Are you changing your root view controller in response to the login?

Comment: iam getting this problem only in iOS 5.1,iOS 5 iOS 4.3 and in iOS 6 no problem

Comment: may be is there any feature in my app which is included in iOS 6 only

Comment: i have a log in view in that view i have a Facebook log in option if click on this my app home screen should appear but my problem is it my  home screen  appears on the log in view

Comment: @siva, we need to know more about the problem to help you better. Edit your original post and provide: 1) More detailed information on what you mean by "fails as described." Is there an error message? If so, post it. Does the app crash? If so, on what line. Etc... 2) The full code from the .h and .m files for your AppDelegate (or wherever you're performing the logic that's causing the error).

Comment: u can my max code in above link

Comment: my problem is when i log in with face book to my app both views are one on the other

Comment: the interesting part is its fine in iOS 6 simulator in iOS<5.1 only aim facing the problem

Comment: @Aaron is there any problem with my code

Comment: @siva, I'm not totally sure what the problem is. What do you mean by "it fails as described". Can you explain by editing your original post  what is supposed to happen, and what is *not* happening that should be?

Comment: Part of your problem might be that in your AppDelegate you create an `AppViewController` object, then a `UserAccount` object (another view controller?) I'm guessing, and then a `Logout` object (also another view controller?). You then add those view controllers to a tab bar controller property. Then a little later on you create another `AppViewController` and `Login` and add them to a new UITabBarController. Finally, you display the TabBarController's view in the window.

Comment: nothing  my view appears on my previous view

Comment: have u seen my total code

Comment: is there any thing which is included in iOS 6 ?

Comment: bcoz my app works fine in iOS 6

Comment: Yes, I've read your code. It would help to understand exactly what you want to do and then we could determine where you're going wrong. For example why are you using tab bar controllers like this? It is not the typical use. UITabBarControllers typically don't get presented on top of one another.

Comment: Show me the code that runs when the button is clicked in the first view controller that should take you to the second tab bar controller. Again, this is a-typical of `UITabBarController` use. Please update your original post with that code.

Comment: basically my view controller has two tab bar items like search and login if i click log in it should ask credentials and login with Facebook option is also there

Comment: so after log in my tab bar con gains 3 items like search, my account and log out

Comment: Show me the code that runs when the button is clicked in the first view controller that should take you to the second tab bar controller.

Comment: OK - If you're adding tab bar view controllers at run-time it sounds like you don't need TWO instances of them like you have in your AppDelegate. That might be part of your problem.

Comment: noe in iOS 5 below versions whats happening is if click on Facebook login the view appears on log in view

Comment: no my tabor showing three items no problem but my text fields and button are coming back of my view

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what the exact problem is. Part of that is that you're not fully explaining what is going on in your project. What is going on with your tab bars, why you're creating two of them, what the Facebook integration has to do with this, etc... you've still not bothered to share the code that changes the views for you: Where is the click code that does this as you've described: "When I click on the login button present in one view controller, it should take me to other tabbarController"

Comment: Final comment: You need to be very thorough in your original post abou twhat you want your app to do and what it is not doing. In your case you need to post your code and now I'm thinking it might help to include pictures or diagrams of the UI as you would like to see it. I can't help you because I don't understand the problem.

Comment: now let us see my code  http://pastie.org/7332922

Comment: shall i add ascreenshot

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you just want to switch tabs programmatically in response to the login? If so, you shouldn't be using `presentModalViewController:`. The correct way to switch tabs is using a UITabBarController method.

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
```

or

```
[self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:self.myOtherViewController];
```

Comment: iam not not switching the tabs iam creating another view from root view controller

Comment: do u understand my problem

Comment: @siva, you need to post all the code in your app delegate header (.h) and implementation (.m) files. Otherwise it's hard to tell what exactly the problem is. You also need to post any error messages you see in Xcode. Saying that your app just "fails as described" is not very helpful. Help us understand what that means.

Comment: i posted my app delegate file

Comment: @Aaron do u understand whats my real problem

Comment: one view appears on another view only below iOS<=5.1 versions only in iOS 6 there is no problem really

Comment: its very needy plz respond

Comment: @Aaron the remaining part just srvices